# Storing string inputs in a list

Tags: python, list

I've been given a small task - to get the user to input a limerick, and for the program to store each line in a list as the line is entered. (I then have to print the limerick back)
This is my current code:

```
limerick_line = []
for i in range(5):
    limerick_line[i].append = input("Type in a limerick line. ")
print(limerick_line[5])
```

I know I'm doing quite a lot wrong, but I'm not exactly sure how to get it right. The current error is "list index out of range".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to use `limerick_line.append(input('enter line: '))` - no need to try and index it... And your final `print` can be just `print(limerick_line)` or loop over it:

```
for line in limerick_line:
    print(line)
```

So, corrected code is:

```
limerick_line = []
for i in range(5):
    limerick_line.append( input("Type in a limerick line. ") )
for line in limerick_line:
    print(line)
```